# get the account name from SID using Perl

Tags: windows, perl

On my Windows 10 machine I am using `Win32::LookupAccountSID()` to get the SID by account. In cmd.exe I run:

```
whoami /user
```

I grab the SID from the output and use it on the below `$sid` variable but the account printed is empty any idea what is wrong with the script?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32;
my $account;
my $domain;
my $sidtype;

my $sid = 'S-1-5-21-1994326832-1066739575-5522801-113721';

Win32::LookupAccountSID(undef,$sid,$account,$domain,$sidtype);

print $account;
```

Comment: I think the SID you input to the function should be different. If I use the `Win32::LookupAccountName()` to get the SID it looks quite different. On my machine I get SID=`        ÿijiîªπ╧≥Hπ┐Θ      Φo     ¡√╪o    Ç≈%    ΦÖ     Φo     x7            σ╗╒o    P≈!    ΦÖ     ΦÖ     Φo     ╪>!    └9#    Φ="    °%    ╪>!    τz┘o    └9#            ΦÖ     Φo     αÿ      ╖≡o    √a     B■╠o    h╛y└u  Φ="            └9#    9      \\╫≥o            Xd4            áÜ4                   Φo                     r═o    Φo     @n     ╕²a     αA     `

Comment: If I use the above SID (instead of the one returned from `whoami` as input to `LookupAccountSID()` it works fine

Comment: do you have any idea if it possible to convert the S-1-15-21 format (the whomai format ) to the format you mentioned?

Comment: You didn't [look](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=win32+sid), did you?

Comment: i look but if its done with Win32 alone it will be great as it comes part of the core .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert the SID to binary format before calling `Win32::LookupAccountSID()`. Here is an example using the [`Win32::Security::SID`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Security::SID) module to convert to binary format:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32;
use Win32::Security::SID;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
{
    my $system = undef;
    my $account;
    my $domain;
    my $sidtype;
    my $stringsid = 'S-1-5-21-1768581528-3487803020-3219343602-1001';
    my $sid = Win32::Security::SID::ConvertStringSidToSid($stringsid);
    Win32::LookupAccountSID($system, $sid, $account, $domain, $sidtype);
    print Dumper({account => $account, domain => $domain, sidtype => $sidtype});
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'domain' => 'DESKTOP-43CR0B8',
          'sidtype' => 1,
          'account' => 'hakon'
        };
```